# Why this script didn't work?

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# !=1 ]
then
   echo Usage: A single argument which is the directory to backup
   exit
fi
if [ ! -d ~/projects/$1 ]
then
   echo 'The given directory does not seem to exist (possible typo)'
   exit
fi
date=`date +%F`
if [ -d ~/projectbackups/$1_date ]
then
  echo 'this project has been backed up today, overwrite?'
  read answer
  if [ $answer != 'y' ]
  then
    exit
  fi
else
  mkdir ~/projectbackups/$1_$date
fi
cp -R ~/projects/$1 ~/projectbackups/$1_$date
echo Backup of $1 completed
```

And i created sub-folder result under projects folder like this:

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 result]# pwd
/root/projects/result
```

But when executing the script, it always throw a error:

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 bash-tut]# ./pj-backup.sh /root/projects/result/
./pj-backup.sh: line 2: [: 1: unary operator expected
The given directory does not seem to exist (possible typo)
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 bash-tut]# ./pj-backup.sh resutl
./pj-backup.sh: line 2: [: 1: unary operator expected
The given directory does not seem to exist (possible typo)
```

Can you guys help me how to fix it, please?

Comment: line 2 : no space between '!=' and '1' ! use double brackets `[[ $# != 1 ]]`

Comment: Silly me, didn't notice that >.< Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 2, you have missed a space between the conditional operator `!=` and the argument (`1`):

```
[ $# != 1 ]
```

**Example:**

```
$ set -- foo bar

$ [ $# !=1 ] && echo "OK"
bash: [: 2: unary operator expected

$ [ $# != 1 ] && echo "OK"
OK
```

Also you are necessaroly doing string comparison, which can fail in many such cases e.g. what if the output of `$#` (replace this with some other variable) was designed to be shown as `01` instead of `1`. So while doing arithmetic comparisons, use arithmetic comparison operator, `-ne` in this case:

```
[ $# -ne 1 ]
```

Or

```
(( $# != 1 ))
```